# I want to group something to become a dictionary and list. Also group them based on the heading

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, grouping

I want to group this following data into a dictionaries and add the names section and grade in a list

**My input data:**

```
mystring = """STUDENT;SECTION;GRADE
    Abordo;BSIT4A;2.25
    Agustin;BSIT4A;1.75
    Asiatico;BSIT4A;3.00
    Asilo;BSIT4A;2.75
    Bernabe;BSIT4A;2.25
    Borja;BSIT4A;2.00
    Botabara;BSIT4A;3.00
    Cagoco;BSIT4A;3.00
    Cariño;BSIT4A;3.00
    Cruz;BSIT4A;3.00
    Dapatnapo;BSIT4A;3.00
    Darupan;BSIT4A;2.25
    Delos Reyes;BSIT4A;3.00
    Ono;BSIT4A;3.00
    Torres;BSIT4A;2.50
    Ugale;BSIT4A;2.25
    Elpedes;BSIT4B;3.00
    Endozo;BSIT4B;2.50
    Estrada;BSIT4B;3.00
    Evangelista;BSIT4B;2.75
    Fernandez;BSIT4B;3.00
    Flores;BSIT4B;3.00
    Gayeta;BSIT4B;2.25
    Gernale;BSIT4B;2.25
    Guarino;BSIT4B;2.50
    Lecaros;BSIT4B;3.00
    Legarda;BSIT4B;2.50
    Longcop;BSIT4B;2.75
    Mabansag;BSIT4B;2.75
    Malaluan;BSIT4B;2.50
    Manaba;BSIT4B;2.25
    Manarin;BSIT4B;3.00
    Mengol;BSIT4B;3.00
    Opriasa;BSIT4B;2.50
    Pangan;BSIT4B;1.75
    Cortez;BSIT4C;3.00
    Pantilag;BSIT4C;2.25
    Penuliar;BSIT4C;3.00
    Relojo;BSIT4C;3.00
    Reyes;BSIT4C;2.75
    Salazar;BSIT4C;3.00
    Santiago;BSIT4C;2.25
    Seberre;BSIT4C;3.00
    Suayan;BSIT4C;3.00
    Sulit;BSIT4C;3.00
    Tejada;BSIT4C;2.50
    Tura;BSIT4C;2.25
    Tuvieron;BSIT4C;1.75
    Vicente;BSIT4C;2.25
    Yacub;BSIT4C;2.75"""
```

**My code so far:**

```
a = mystring.split("\n")
for i, j in enumerate(a):
     a[i] = j.replace(";",":")

heading = mystring[0]
```

**I want to separate them based on groups like:**

```
{
    'STUDENT': ['Abordo', 'Agustin', ...],
    'SECTION': ['BSIT4A', 'BSIT4A', ...],
    'GRADE': [2.25, 1.75, ...]
}
```

I am new in python if you can tell me I really appreciate it.
I already did this so that I can change the string into a semi column separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a shortened version of your data:

```
mystring = """STUDENT;SECTION;GRADE
    Abordo;BSIT4A;2.25
    Agustin;BSIT4A;1.75
    Asiatico;BSIT4A;3.00
    Asilo;BSIT4A;2.75
    Bernabe;BSIT4A;2.25
    Borja;BSIT4A;2.00
    Botabara;BSIT4A;3.00"""
```

The first thing I would probably do is reshape it into a "list of lists" or a list of dictionaries. Let's do a list of lists.

```
rows = [
    [cell.strip() for cell in row.split(";")]
    for row in mystring.split("\n")
]
```

at this point we can view what we have with a `print()`:

```
[
    ['STUDENT', 'SECTION', 'GRADE'],
    ['Abordo', 'BSIT4A', '2.25'],
    ['Agustin', 'BSIT4A', '1.75'],
    ['Asiatico', 'BSIT4A', '3.00'],
    ['Asilo', 'BSIT4A', '2.75'],
    ['Bernabe', 'BSIT4A', '2.25'],
    ['Borja', 'BSIT4A', '2.00'],
    ['Botabara', 'BSIT4A', '3.00']
]
```

Now we can reshape that using the data in the first row as the keys of a dictionary with corresponding values appended to lists.

```
headers = rows[0]
results = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row_values in rows[1:]:
    for column_index, column_name in enumerate(headers):
        results[column_name].append(row_values[column_index])
```

Again we can print what we have to see:

```
{
    'STUDENT': ['Abordo', 'Agustin', 'Asiatico', 'Asilo', 'Bernabe', 'Borja', 'Botabara'],
    'SECTION': ['BSIT4A', 'BSIT4A', 'BSIT4A', 'BSIT4A', 'BSIT4A', 'BSIT4A', 'BSIT4A'],
    'GRADE': ['2.25', '1.75', '3.00', '2.75', '2.25', '2.00', '3.00']
}
```

Note though that the `pandas` module would do most of the work for you if you wanted to explore it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, there is somethings or code of line I didn't understand but I think I can figure it out somehow. Going to research some of it. Thank you! Big help

Comment: Hi, is there a subtitute for the collections.defaultdict(list)? I don't the import method yet, and I don't know how to use. The data that has been arranged will be used so that I can output them like
@JonSG
STUDENT   SECTION   GRADE
--------------------------------
Abordo     2.15       BSIT4A